# Is there a collection that behaves like a Queue but allows me to get multiple elements at a time?

Tags: java, collections

I am looking for a data structure that behaves like a queue (it could be a queue implementation) but allows me to get multiple elements from the collection (example: the first 15 elements of the queue).

It would be very nice if it doesn't require new dependencies.

Is there anything like that?

The closer I got during my research was the BlockingQueue with the drainTo() method, but this is not what I need.

Comment: I would create my own method which calls poll x times (given as parameter) and returns a new Collection (I don't know if NimChimpsky suggests the same, due to his constant edits, but that's pretty much the way to go)

Comment: Why do you think you need this instead of just taking repeatedly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) implement queue, collection, and list.

You could [poll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#poll()) for the head, or get a [sublist](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#subList(int,%20int)) for the first 15 elements, and then also [removeRange](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#removeRange(int,%20int)) to remove them.

I'd probably just poll 15 times as the sublist/removeRange are going to need to iterate over the elements somehow anyway, therefore the perfromance will be similar.

Comment: I'm still thinking about this or calling the multiple times the queue.poll() as you have suggested earlier. The advantage of the queue.poll() is that I do not need to handle the case that the queue is smaller as the batch size and that I do not have to handle removing the elements manually. I am not sure which code looks better. I am running some performance tests at the moment

Comment: @JSBach I imagine the performance difference would be negligble, look at the source of sublist and removeRange - i think must iterate over the elements.

Comment: Ok, cool. Actually the removeRange is protected, so I can't use it. I would have to call sublist(...).clear(). Anyway, I will iterate the poll 15 times. Thanks for your help, as soon as possible I will mark it as answer

Comment: I agree with the suggestion of *LinkedList* as an implementation. But you should use interfaces as a type of your collections in order to simplify code maintenance.

To respect the [*Queue*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) interface, there is the [*Deque*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) subinterface that provides the ability to go back to the first element (and by the way retrieve the 15 first elements).

*LinkedList* is an implementation of that interface.